# What specific values can a C# double represent that a SQL Server float can't?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm getting an error when I pass a C# double into a SQL Server float parameter.  I know I'm sending in a value that the SQL Server float can't represent, but I can't figure out which one it is.  So, my question is what values can a C# double represent that a SQL Server float can't?

Comment: "The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 ("@fOne"): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision."  I've already verified this is a result of sending in a value that's not representable by the SQL Server float type.

Comment: They represent the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC the values **NaN**, **PositiveInfinity** and **NegativeInfinity** are not supported by SQL Server. You could check for this with the methods **Double.IsNaN(...)** and **Double.IsInfinity(...)**.

Don't use `==` for checking, as these special values are never equal to any other value, not even themselves (e.g. `NaN != NaN`).

Answer (score 0):

A double and a float are the same datatype.  I think your error may be secondary to another issue.  Perhaps your parameter is not getting passed correctly?  Check the actual value of the parameter that is being passed in the data stream.